# cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields'

Tags: python, django, docker

Хочу сделать миграции, пишу `python manage.py makemigrations` и получаю это
Полный Traceback выглядит так:

```
File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from rest_framework import VERSION, exceptions, serializers, status
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)
MacBook-Air-Squidward:api work$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 268, in get_model
    return self.models[model_name.lower()]
KeyError: 'user'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 160, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 211, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 270, in get_model
    raise LookupError(
LookupError: App 'companies' doesn't have a 'user' model.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/clients/models.py", line 11, in <module>
    from loyalty.models import (
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/loyalty/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from shops.models import Shop
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/shops/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 164, in get_user_model
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'companies.user' that has not been installed
MacBook-Air-Squidward:api work$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from rest_framework import VERSION, exceptions, serializers, status
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)
MacBook-Air-Squidward:api work$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from rest_framework import VERSION, exceptions, serializers, status
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)
MacBook-Air-Squidward:api work$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from rest_framework import VERSION, exceptions, serializers, status
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)
MacBook-Air-Squidward:api work$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from rest_framework import VERSION, exceptions, serializers, status
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)
```

файл ****init.py**** из верхнего пути очень большой и не смогу сюда вставить (не нашел в нем ничего про `FieldDoesNotExist`)

в проекте используется django 2.2.6, не знаю какие файлы вам еще показать, пишите, я покажу

буду рад любой помощи

Answer (score 4):

Ваша версия django-allauth имеет неверный импорт для FieldDoesNotExist. Правильный импорт:

```
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist
```

Импорт из django.db.modelsпредположительно работал в более старых версиях Django.

Так же попробуйте обновить django.

Такое решение я нашёл на англоязычном Stack Overflow, вроде бы там такая же проблема. Напишите, помогло ли это Вам.

Comment: Станислав Енягин, я видел этот ответ в СОФ, я разобрался, `django.core.exceptions` работает с 3 версии django, так как у меня 2.2.6, то можно `django.db.models.fields`

Спасибо

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)